# Customised ordering according to column data in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a csv file, which needs to be sorted according a column. The order however is taken from a order.cfg file.
eg.my df looks like this

```
C1,C2,C3
A, 51,60
B, 91,10
M, 31,56
Z, 34,20
```

Now if order.cfg is like below

```
M
Z
```

Then df should be sorted in a way to push up M and Z up

```
C1,C2,C3
M, 31,56
Z, 34,20
A, 51,60
B, 91,10
```

I know how to order according to column values, but here it needs to be done through my configurable order.cfg.

One of my naive approach is to grep each element 1 by 1 in df.

1. grep M in df$C1 take that row in newdf and remove from df
2. rbind newdf with remainder of df

However there must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I read these in as dataframes, 'df1' and 'order.cfg',  with stringsAsFactors=FALSE. This then delivers the desired ordering:

```
> df1[ order(match(df1[[1]], order.cfg[[1]], incomparables=Inf) ),]
  C1 C2 C3
3  M 31 56
4  Z 34 20
1  A 51 60
2  B 91 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `order.cfg` data is read as a `vector` ('v1') with two elements ('M', 'Z'), we change the 'C1' column in 'df1' to `factor` class by specifying the `levels` by concatenating (`c`) the elements that are common in the 'C1' and 'v1' (`intersect(df1$C1, v1)`), followed by the elements that are present in 'C1' and not in 'v1' (`setdiff(df1$C1, v1)`), `order` it and use that as index to reorder the rows of the 'df1'.

```
df2 <- df1[order(factor(df1$C1, levels=c(intersect(df1$C1,v1),
                                               setdiff(df1$C1, v1)))),]
row.names(df2) <- NULL
df2
#  C1 C2 C3
#1  M 31 56
#2  Z 34 20
#3  A 51 60
#4  B 91 10
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('M', 'Z')

df1 <- structure(list(C1 = c("A", "B", "M", "Z"), C2 = c(51L, 91L, 31L, 
34L), C3 = c(60L, 10L, 56L, 20L)), .Names = c("C1", "C2", "C3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```